# Do the relations in a group carry forward to a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G=\langle\, S\,|\,R\, \rangle$ is a finitely presented group and $H=\langle\, S'\,|\,R'\,\rangle$ is a group with generating set $S'\subseteq G$ then does that make $H$ a subgroup of $G$?

Also, If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then do the generators of $H$ satisfy the relations of $G$ as well? Let me give an example :

Let $G=\langle\, s_i:1\leq i\leq 4\,|\, s_i^2=1 \text{ for all }i \text{ and } (s_1s_2)^2=(s_1s_4)^2=(s_2s_3)^2=(s_3s_4)^2=1\rangle$

Let $H=\langle\, a,b\,|\,ab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}=1\,\rangle$ where $a=s_3s_1$ and $b=s_4s_2$.

1. Is $H$ a subgroup of $G$ above?
2. If so, can we say $ab=s_3s_1s_4s_2=s_3s_4s_1s_2=s_4s_3s_2s_1=s_4s_2s_3s_1=ba$. This means that $H$ should also have the relation $aba^{-1}b^{-1}=1$? This seems wrong to me.

Could someone please clarify what is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: In principle, if a property holds for a larger set (associativity in a group), then it will hold for a subset (associativity in a subgroup).

Comment: Yes. That's what I thought. However the outcome in this case confuses me. I have a group ($H$) that is clearly not abelain but it is when I use associativity and the relations in $G$.

Comment: Your statement "Let $H = \langle a,b \mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}=1 \rangle$ where $a=s_2s_2$ and $b=s_4s_2$" doesn't make sense. What you probably want to ask is whether the map $a \mapsto s_3s_1, b \mapsto s_4s_2$ extends to a homomorphism $H \to G$, and the answer is no, because the elements $A:=s_3s_1$ and $B:=s_4s_2$ of $G$ do not satisfy the relation $AB^{-1}A^{-1}B^{-1}=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When forming the group $H=\langle S'|R'\rangle$, you only consider $S'$ as a set. In particular, you forget that $S'$ is a subset of a group, and thus that there are some operations you can do with its elements. So $H$ has no reason in general to be a subset of $G$.

So in your example, when you consider the group $H=\langle a,b |ab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle $, you don't actually care about who $a$ and $b$ are, so $H$ has no relation with $G$.

On the other hand, if $H$ is really a subgroup of $G$, then any relation that holds in $G$ will of course still hold in $H$.

Answer (score 2):

There are two notions of relations in groups: one is defining relations, and other is called laws that group can satisfy.

Every group $G$ can be written in form $F(X)/N$, where $F(X)$ is a free group on $X$ — some generating set for $G$, and $N$ is the kernel of surjection $\pi: F(X) \to G$. Defining relations $R$ for given $\pi$ is some subset of $N$ such that $N$ is the minimal normal subgroup of $F(X)$ containing $R$, called the normal closure of $R$ in $F(X)$ They are not determined uniquely: from $R$ you can produce $R'$ changing one of its elements to its inverse or multiplying one by another. Their normal closures, of course, will be same.

Laws in group $G$ (more generally, in some class of groups) are different thing: they are words in (infinite) alphabet (alternatively, elements of free group with countable number of generators) with the property that for *every* homomorphism to $G$ (to every group in class respectively) they fall into its kernel. Typical examples are

- $[x, y] := x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$: group satisfying this law is abelian
- $[xy, z][yz, x][zx, y]$: this law holds in every group (i. e. reduced word corresponding to it is empty)
- $[[x, y], z][[y, z], x][[z, x], y]$: this law holds in groups with abelian commutator subgroup

As it follows from definition, if a law holds in $G$, then it holds in every factorgroup and subgroup of $G$. Somewhat less trivial result is that if a law
holds in $G$ and $H$, then in holds in $G \times H$. Conversely, [Birkhoff theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)) states that every collection of groups closed under passing to subgroups, factors and products is defined by some set of laws.

You can look at two groups: one is $\langle x, y \, | \, x^2, y^2 \rangle$, the infinite dihedral group, and second is $\langle x, y \, | \, g^2 = 1 \,$for every$\, g \rangle$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z / 2 \times \mathbb Z / 2$. Contemplating a bit on this may help.